# Finding aggregate time across multiple text log files

Tags: shell, scripting, vbscript, batch-file

I have a lot of log files being generated by my automation scripts, which also log the time the script was started and when it finished. There are some redendancies in the same, where the individual tests failed.

I wish to get an aggregate of the times to work out how much time it took to run all the scripts (~200 scripts, with ~8000 test cases). The problem is that sometimes the script aborts without running a single case, by the framework still records the time to the log file. I want to do something like:

```
Pick specific files with the same script name (as a single script can be run multiple times and has a log file for each of these runs in its name)
    Read the Log file for a single script
        If FAIL value = (total test cases) then skip the log file
        If ABORT value = (total test cases) then skip the log file
        If PASS value = (total test cases -1) then record the Start and End times to the output file
    Goto the next script in the same name set
Goto the next set of script files
```

Also, once the above operation completes, I want to aggregate and average out the times and find the average time for each script and for the complete run.

Is there any simple way to do it using shell scripts or DOS batch? I do not want to write a full-fledged program for this implementation? Would be great if someone can inform if the same can be done with VBScript and how?

File Details:

Name of the LOG files:

```
TestScriptA_20120201.LOG
TestScriptA_20120202.LOG
TestScriptA_20120203.LOG
TestScriptB_20120201.LOG
TestScriptB_20120202.LOG
TestScriptC_20120202.LOG
TestScriptD_20120203.LOG
```

File Contents:

```
Report File:        TestScriptA_20120203.LOG
Date Created:       14-02-2012
Time Started:       09:21:03
Test Database:      staging
Processor:          proc_stage
Test Login:         ABC
Test Date :         14-02-2012


Test #1                          Status : Pass
Purpose  = First Test
DataFile = master1.tda
StepName = TS1 - Test Step 1


Test #2                          Status : Pass
Purpose  = First Test
DataFile = master2.tda
StepName = TS1 - Test Step 2




Test Step Results:     First Test

Total Tests:                         2
Tests run:                           2
Aborted Tests:                       0
Passed Tests:                        2
Failed Tests:                        0


Script finished at 09:26:45 on 14-02-2012
Execution Time : 00:05:42
-------------------------------  End Of Report -----------------------------
```

Comment: This may be done via a .BATch file, although not in a too simple way. Please, post specific details on file names (Names of the script and log files? How we know that multiple files belongs to the same script?) What is the format of the lines? Where FAIL, ABORT and PASS values appear? Where are the Start and End times and in wich format? Etc...

Comment: @Aacini Added the file name and contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed that the script files have .BAT extension, so this Batch file can not be in the same directory of the script and log files, but must run on it. Perhaps you need to add a CD command at beginning...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Initialize total time
set totalTime=0
set total=0
rem For each script file...
for %%s in (*.bat) do (
   rem Initialize aggregate time for this script
   set "aggregateTime[%%~Ns]=0"
   set "%%~Ns=0"
   rem For each log file created by this script file...
   for %%l in ("%%~Ns*.log") do (
      rem Get Passed Tests
      for /F "tokens=3" %%p in ('findstr /C:"Passed Tests:" %%l') do set passed=%%p
      rem If Passed Tests is greater than zero...
      if !passed! gtr 0 (
         rem Get Start and End times
         for /F "tokens=3" %%s in ('findstr /C:"Time Started:" %%l') do set start=%%s
         for /F "tokens=4" %%e in ('findstr /C:"Script finished" %%l') do set end=%%e
         rem Record Start and End times to output file
         echo Log file: %%l, Start time: !start!, End time: !end!
         rem Get Elapsed time
         rem BEWARE! Result in log file have a space in "Execution Time :" text
         rem If it is deleted, change 4 by 3 in the line below
         for /F "tokens=4" %%e in ('findstr /C:"Execution Time" %%l') do set elapsed=%%e
         rem Convert elapsed time to seconds
         for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ("!elapsed!") do (
            set "elapsed=((1%%a %% 100)*60+(1%%b %% 100))*60+(1%%c %% 100)"
         )
         rem Add elapsed time to aggregates
         set /A "aggregateTime[%%~Ns]+=elapsed"
         set /A "%%~Ns+=1"
         set /A totalTime+=elapsed
         set /A total+=1
      )      
   )
   echo --------------------------------------------------
   echo/
)
echo/
echo --------------------------------------------------
echo Aggregate and average times for each script (in seconds):
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set aggregateTime[') do (
   set /A "average=%%b/%%a"
   echo %%a  !aggregateTime[%%a]!  !average!
)
echo/
echo Aggregate and average total times (in seconds):
set /A average=totalTime/total
echo !totalTime!  !average!
```

This is a first version. Several details may be fixed or adjusted, like converting the aggregate and average times to HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: Am getting following error:  
Aggregate and average total times (in seconds):
Divide by zero error.
0

Will try to work around it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @gagneet: What about previous average times of each script? If these times are correct, it is very strange that the total average time mark an error, because both calculations are practically the same!

Comment: Both the average times are coming up with the same error. I think the script is unable to properly parse and verify the time and hence no value is stored in either (or there is a scope problem). Am trying to understand and work out what could be the issue.